# Could you show the intractibility of SAT by showing that the number of variables contributing to an arbitrary unsatisfied clause is not constant?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, logic, proof-techniques, satisfiability

Preface: This is not an attempted proof at P vs NP

Starting with some CNF Boolean expression ϕ, by the rules of logical disjunction, a clause is only unsatisfied if each of the literals in it are themselves forced into being unsatisfied. A trivial example is (x OR y) with the interpretation XY=00. Non-trivially, we can find a contradiction, ϕ ↔ x ∧ -x. Since a Boolean variable can only be true or false, some clause in ϕ will remain unsatisfied depending on which interpretation of X we choose.

ϕ is satisfied by an interpretation *I*, iff *I* doesn't leave any of the clauses in ϕ unsatisfied, following the rules of logical conjunction. If each *I* contains some unsatisfied clause, then ϕ is unsatisfiable.

ϕ = (a OR c) AND (b OR d) AND (-c OR -d)
ϕ[00CD] = (0 OR c) AND (0 OR d) AND (-c OR -d)

Due to the clausal structure of ϕ above, any *I* containing A=0 and B=0 will always force the expression into being unsatisfied. Even if we add more clauses or more variables, the existence of these clauses in ϕ means that any such *I* will always be an unsatisfying interpretation.

Following from this, if ϕ also contained clauses which acted analogously on interpretations containing AB=01, AB=10, or AB=11, then there'd be no satisfying assignment containing A and B. Since all maximal interpretations will contain some assignment for A and B, ϕ is made unsatisfiable based off of these 2, out of a potential n, variables.

ϕ' = (a OR b) AND (a OR c) AND (-b OR -c)
ϕ'' = (-a OR d) AND (-a OR e) AND (-d OR -e)

We could create an example with 1 variable as well. ϕ' has no satisfying *I* which contains A=0 and ϕ'' has no satisfying *I* which contains A=1, as the respective assignment to A allows us to generate a contradiction in that expression. If we have the expression Φ = ϕ' AND ϕ'', then we'd automatically have an unsatisfiable expression caused by the complete inability to assign A.

So could we tie up 3, 4, 5 or m $\le$ n variables such that each of the 2<sup>m</sup> ways of assigning them forces some unsatisfied clause? If m is the maximum number of variables which we could tie up to force some arbitrary clause of size k into being unsatisfied, then if you take each of the (n choose m) possible groups of variables and you try all 2<sup>m</sup> ways of assigning them, as long as each variable group has at least one *I* which doesn't leave some clause unsatisfied, then your expression is satisfiable.

I conjecture that when k = 2, m = 2, no matter the problem instance. This would mean that no group of 3 or more variables is both necessary and sufficient to leave a clause with only 2 literals unsatisfied. However, once k $\ge$ 3, then m $\le$ n. We could force a clause of 3 literals to be unsatisfied with 3, 4, or 5 variables, only bounded by n or the total number of variables in ϕ.

I have not given any proof that 2SAT and 3SAT have the value of m that I think they do, but what I want to know is if the conjecture is true, would that mean that the classes are different? Would such a structural difference, if proven to be true, be able to separate the two classes of problems?

**Edited** to create a more technical question to clarify the information I'm looking for

**Edited** Major edit to address comments

Comment: SE is not a free paper review service. If you are concerned about why your paper was rejected, I suggest you directly contact the journal's editor(s).

Comment: @dkaeae Thanks for the comment. I did ask if there was any feedback available to me, but got no response, though this question isn't about why the paper was rejected, but about the ability for the method I outlined above to separate SAT classes

Comment: Please don't invent your own terminology for standard concepts. "Contradiction" already has a meaning, and it is not the meaning that you're using. It's not reasonable to require everyone who reads your work to learn these new definitions, and this is exactly the sort of thing that causes papers to get rejected without any substantive comments. It's nearly impossible to check that somebody's work is correct if, every time they use a well-understood word like "contradiction", the reader has to remember that it actually means "falsifying assignment".

Comment: The guidance at [I believe I have solved a famous open problem. How do I convince people in the field that I am not a crank?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/18491/10685) is relevant.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Thanks for the feedback. I updated the question to explain why I used terminology like contradiction despite its well known meaning. The different perspective gave me more tools which are needed later on in the method I described. Also edited the question so the information I'm looking for is clearer

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it proposes a solution to the P vs NP problem.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Hi Yuval, I'm struggling to understand how this question is off-topic. It seems pretty straight-forward, assuming 2SAT and 3SAT have the structural properties I described above, would that be enough to separate them? If I wrote the full proof for why I think they do have the properties, then I'd definitely understand your comment, as well as the one from dkaeae, but I'm asking specifically about the strength of a hypothetical successful proof of the properties, regardless of if I have one. Could you explain how I can better ask that if this question is too ambiguous?

Comment: In paragraph one you redefined "contradiction". In paragraph two you are using "contradiction" according to its standard meaning. As you seem to be unaware even of your own terminological conventions, the rest of the text is not worth spending time on.

Comment: @AndrejBauer That was an explanation to why it was being done, though it could have been ordered better, not ignorance on the terminology. I'll refer you to the line "a contradiction can be represented by the clause it makes unsatisfied, not only by the invalid conjunction of statements"

Comment: I've updated the question to include the type of specific answer I'm looking for, really a yes, no, or undetermined. Please, I just need help, not derision. If I can improve the question or ask better ones, please give me tips about what exactly is wrong, otherwise the next time I ask a question, I'm going to do the wrong stuff again, leading to another unwelcomed question. I truly, honestly, and sincerely need help answering this question, I need to know if I've wasted all this time looking for something that doesn't actually show anything interesting.

Comment: @Naiim Checking people's work is off-topic. I'm sorry that you feel that people are being derisive but I don't see that (except in one possible case). If you do feel that people are being rude to you, please flag the relevant comments for moderator attention. In the web interface, you'll see a little grey flag next to each comment, which you can click on; in the mobile interface, you need to tap on the comment and a list of options will appear.

Comment: And I would reiterate, redefining the word "contradiction" does not make anything easier. It makes things confusing, and confused people make mistakes.

Comment: I have attempted to read your question again, but it is not written in a way I can understand. I suggest you rewrite your answer and take the following into account: 1. Start your answer with a complete and formal definition of your conjecture, leave  examples and arguments in favor or against your conjecture until the end of your question. You may wish to define other concepts to aid in stating your conjecture, but be sure to _properly define all terms you use_. In particular, you should define 'k-contradiction' and 'm'. This way, your main problem should be clear.

Comment: 2. Try to avoid redefining existing terms, this confuses people to no end. Perhaps you can call $x\wedge \neg x$ a _contradicting pair_ and go from there. 3. Try to use MathJax for your formulas. If you have done this, there is a much larger chance that we will be able to help you than for this question in its current form.

Comment: @Discretelizard Thanks for that feedback! I made some edits to the question to try to tackle those issues as well as the comments made by David

Comment: OK, thanks for editing. But, look, no amount of editing is going to fix this fundamental problem: REQUESTS TO CHECK YOUR WORK ARE OFF-TOPIC, HERE. I'm sorry to shout, but you've been told this several times, now, and you don't seem to be listening. The advice about not redefining standard terms, and so on, was advice for how to improve your paper. Using it to improve your question doesn't affect the fundamental issue that your question is not appropriate for this site. (I'd suggest somewhere more appropriate, if I knew one; unfortunately, I don't.)

Comment: How about https://www.reddit.com/r/math/ or https://www.reddit.com/r/computerscience/, they like to discuss all sorts of things there, and the pool of responders is much larger

Comment: @DavidRicherby That's the thing I'm not sure I fully understand. There's no work that I've done, I just asked a long question. However, I've taken Andrej's suggestion and moved over to [r/math](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/ajx68y/has_this_combinatorics_problem_regarding_the/). Thanks for the feedback, I used it to improve the question over there.